# Estimation of X in Gaussian noise

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, complex-numbers

Given 
$\textbf{x}=[x_1 x_2 ... x_n]^T$ where $\textbf{x} \in \{ 0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \}^n, a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\textbf{z} = \left\{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n \right\}$ where $z_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is a Complex Gaussian RV with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose we observe $\textbf{y}$

$$\textbf{y} = H\textbf{x}+\textbf{z}$$

where $H$ is known and its elements are independent complex Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1 in $\mathbb{C}$ i.e. complex numbers. How can I estimate $\textbf{x}$ observing $\textbf{y}$ when I only want to know whether $x_i$ is zero or non-zero? i.e. I don't want to distinguish between $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and only want to estimate whether $x_i$ was zero or non_zero?
Is there any iterative way of finding this out?

Comment: Are the $z_i$ also independent complex Gaussian random variables?

Comment: This sounds like a Rayleigh-fading wireless communications problem.

Comment: You are right! Its a Rayleigh Fading wireless communication problem. $z_i$ are also independent complex Gaussian RVs.

Comment: What do you mean by you want to "estimate" whether the $x_i$ are zero or non-zero? Do you mean you want to test the hypothesis $H_{0,i}: x_i = 0$ vs. $H_{1,i}: x_i \neq 0$? Are you interested in individual hypotheses or a *joint* hypothesis, say, that they are *all* zero? Are you trying to minimize the probability of error of your decision or control the Type I Error rate (which you might call the "false alarm" probability)?